# Проблема с Visual Studio. Некорректно отображается интерфейс

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Помогите, пожалуйста, у меня пропал интерфейс в Visual studio. Пробовал переустанавливать, но ничего не изменилось.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще после установки возникает следующая ошибка:
Не удалось установить Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас с драйверами видюхи возможно что-то не так. Обновите винду и дрова.

Comment: У меня установлены самые свежие драйвера

Comment: Откуда скачивали студию? Какая версия?

Comment: С официального сайта, последняя на данный момент версия

Comment: У меня такая же проблема Нашел решение?

Answer (score 0):

> Еще после установки возникает следующая ошибка: Не удалось установить
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi

Гугл выдал такие варианты: возможно антивирус блокирует установку этого файла. Отключи защиту и попробуй еще раз. Также может нужно сначала обновить винду (установить последние обновления) и потом попробовать установить еще раз.

Короче, это у тебя из-за винды. Попробуй кеш винды почистить, может вдруг и из-за этого. Если вообще  ничего не поможет, установи нормальную винду. А не всякие репаки.

Comment: а из-за kms может быть проблема?

Comment: @kurS может....